# git patch shows tab but file shows space

Tags: git, vim

Git patch:

```
+#define SECT_4K                        BIT(0)
+#define E_FSR                  BIT(1)
+#define SST_WR                 BIT(2)
+#define WR_QPP                 BIT(3)
```

File:

```
#define SECT_4K                 BIT(0)
#define E_FSR                   BIT(1)
#define SST_WR                  BIT(2)
#define WR_QPP                  BIT(3)
```

The problem I've observed is when I edited the file on `SECT_4K` line it took 3 tabs to move `BIT(0)` in proper line, out of 3 tabs the when I did tab on first time it moves only space(not tab space) and then it moves two tabs positions correctly. ie the reason I have 3 tabs on git file and `BIT(0)` moved. I'm using vim editor and don't have any setting on ~/.vimrc file.

Answer (score 1):

I think both show tabs, and you just misinterpret what you are seeing.
Your tab size is configured to be 8 characters.
`#define SECT_4K` are 15 characters, so pressing Tab will move to character 16, again to 24, again to 32.

In the diff output, there is one more additional character in the beginning, the `+`, so `+#define SECT_4K` now has 16 characters, the first tab will move to 24, the second to 32 and the third to 40.

If you change your tab size, it will display differently. But ultimately I'd say everything is ok and you just misinterpret the output.

Comment: + at #define doesn't need to count it's an addition of git format-patch, but you said pressing tab move to 16 in file shows space because 15 characters with one space and at the same time ie shown a tab space in git file ie what am wondering.

Comment: Whether you think it does need to count or not is insignificant. The displayed line contains this character and your display device (the console) formats accordingly. If you don't like this, make your console or whatever set an addtional tabstop at character 1 when displaying git diffs. Pressing tab does not show space, but it shows a tab with width one, as the next tab stop is at position 16.